# Android OnResume on child Fragment is not calling

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalstateexception, onresume

I am using slidingmenu in my project and all the sidemenu items  are fragments.
My home fragment has two tabs that are fragments too. (fragment A has two child fragments as tabs; fragment B and C). Whenever I come back from other fragments  to the homefragment, the `OnResume()` of fragmentA is getting called. How to call the `onResume()` of FragmentB which is a child of FragmentA ?

I want to refresh the views in FragmentB whenever homefragment is loaded, the only option I think is to do in `OnResume()`.

I tried calling the `refreshFragment()` method in `onResume()` of homefragment (i.e fragmentA) but it is throwing an error saying fragment is not attached to the activity.

**Code of onResume() of FragemntA**

```
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(mTabHost.getCurrentTab());

        boolean settingschanged = sharedPrefrences.getBoolean(Constants.CHECK_CHANGE, false);
        int unit = sharedPrefrences.getInt(Constants.DIMENSION_UNIT, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefrences.edit();
        switch (mTabHost.getCurrentTab()) {
        case 0:
            ((Outer) mFragments.get(0)).refreshView(unit);
            ((Outer) mFragments.get(0)).refreshFragment(settingschanged);

            editor.putInt(Constants.DIMENSION_UNIT, unit);
            editor.commit();
            break;
        case 1:
            ((Inner) mFragments.get(1)).refreshView(unit);
            editor.putInt(Constants.DIMENSION_UNIT, unit);
            editor.commit();
            break;
        default:
            ((Outer) mFragments.get(0)).refreshView(unit);
            editor.putInt(Constants.DIMENSION_UNIT, unit);
            editor.commit();
        }


    }
```

Below is the crash am getting:

```
09-16 14:13:34.608: E/AndroidRuntime(5758): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment Outer{d34ce61} not attached to Activity
09-16 14:13:34.608: E/AndroidRuntime(5758):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:639)
```

Comment: dont refresh it in onResume there are many other methods to refresh

Comment: @siddhesh can you elaborate what other methods i can use

Comment: in **onResume()** of fragment a, please check which child fragment is currently running and by knowing that just call required function of child fragment by using its object in Fragment A.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method and it helps me many times. Basically it depends upon your requirement

```
 @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
}
```

Comment: problem is I want to make it visible . i.e,  when ever I call fragment A the child fragment  fragmentB's  onResume() should be called.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this is not the only/best way to do it. But this should solve the problem as it did to me.

Please write refresh() methods in both FragmentCanali and FragmentPreferiti Fragments.

```
public class ListCanali extends Fragment implements OnPageChangeListener{
private MyAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public View OnCreateView (...) {
...
if(mAdapter == null) {
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
}
viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
...
}

...
@Override
public void OnPageSelected (int position) {
switch (position){
        case 0 : ((FragmentCanali)adapter.getItem(position)).refresh();
        case 1 : ((FragmentPreferiti)adapter.getItem(position)).refresh();
    }
}}
```

It will be cleaner if you extend both the fragments from a base fragment which has abstract refresh() method.

In the onPageSelected() you can just call `((BaseFragment)adapter.getItem(position)).refresh()`